# How do I pin a view to the edges of a screen?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How do I pin a view (in this case, a label/text) to an edge of a screen with `SwiftUI`? With Storyboards I would just use `AutoLayout` but that isn't available with `SwiftUI`.

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
    VStack {
        HStack {
            Text("Label")
            Spacer()
        }
        Spacer()
    }
```

`Spacer` in `VStack` will make sure `HStack` is at the top, `Spacer` in `HStack` will make sure `Text` is all they way to the left. You can also solve this with alignments.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your main content in a special container called `GeometryReader`. Its default size is the same as its parent so if it is the root view it will pin the contents to the screen edges like AutoLayout.

```
GeometryReader { in geometry
    YourContentView().frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is here to find a way to  pin a view *x points* from the top, you can do this:

```
VStack {
        Spacer()
            .frame(height: 40)
        Text("Space me")
        Spacer()
    }
```

You'll need both spacers. This can be a bit counter-intuitive if you're coming from Auto Layout but it's actually quite convenient. The spacer at the bottom of your VStack will "push" your VStack views from the default (i.e. centered) y position toward the top until it meets resistance – by default the top edge of the safe area. You can then push the resting point down by x points with the top spacer, giving a similar effect as Auto Layout's top constraint.

Comment: You can do this through padding. You don't need a spacer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this modifier on your view

```
  .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity,
         minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
```

SwiftUI uses minimum needed space for any view, to increase it you may use different approaches depending on the situation.
Also it's possible to use relativeSize() modifier, but I didn't get yet when it works

Comment: How do you want to see the changes on the transparent background?:) Call the background modifier to change the color right after the frame modifier)